# Extraction of the least significant bit of a pixel

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to extract the least significant bit (LSB) of each pixel in an image. I want to know what is the value of LSB in each pixel, whether it is 1 or 0. How do I do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`bitget`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitget.html) function and specify the bit position of 1, denoting the LSB of each pixel.  Assuming your image is stored in `A`, simply do:

```
B = bitget(A, 1);
```

`B` will be the same size as `A` which tells you the LSB of each pixel in the image.